# Get word frequency rankings of words in postgreSQL for each label

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgreSQL database with the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE dummy (
created_at TIMESTAMPTZ,
tweet TEXT,
label INT);
```

The following data is inserted:

```
INSERT INTO dummy VALUES ('2020-12-18 00:00:00+00', 'foo squared', 1);
INSERT INTO dummy VALUES ('2020-12-18 00:00:00+00', 'foo fox', 2);
INSERT INTO dummy VALUES ('2020-12-18 00:00:00+00', 'foo bar', 3);
INSERT INTO dummy VALUES ('2020-12-18 00:00:00+00', 'raven bar', 2);
INSERT INTO dummy VALUES ('2020-12-17 00:00:00+00', 'bar standard', 1);
INSERT INTO dummy VALUES ('2020-12-17 00:00:00+00', 'bar none', 2);
INSERT INTO dummy VALUES ('2020-12-17 00:00:00+00', 'bar none', 3);
```

I have the following query that fetches the frequency of each word in the table and ranks them, grouping by day:

```
select *
from (
    select date_trunc('day', created_at) as created_day, word, count(*) as cnt,
        rank() over(partition by date_trunc('day', created_at) order by count(*) desc) rn
    from dummy d
    cross join lateral regexp_split_to_table(
        trim(regexp_replace(tweet, '\y(rt|co|https|amp|none)\y', '', 'g')),
        '\s+'
    ) w(word)
    group by created_day, word
) t
where (created_day > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '10 days') 
    and word IS NOT NULL
order by created_day DESC, rn;
```

Result:

```
      created_day       |   word   | cnt | rn
------------------------+----------+-----+----
 2020-12-18 00:00:00+00 | foo      |   3 |  1
 2020-12-18 00:00:00+00 | bar      |   2 |  2
 2020-12-18 00:00:00+00 | squared  |   1 |  4
 2020-12-18 00:00:00+00 | raven    |   1 |  4
 2020-12-18 00:00:00+00 | fox      |   1 |  4
 2020-12-17 00:00:00+00 | bar      |   3 |  1
 2020-12-17 00:00:00+00 | standard |   1 |  2
```

I would like to group by the label so that the new query shows the word rankings filtered by label like so:

```
      created_day       |   word   | cnt | rn | label |
------------------------+----------+-----+--------------
 2020-12-18 00:00:00+00 | foo      |   3 |  1 |     1 |
 2020-12-18 00:00:00+00 | bar      |   2 |  2 |     1 |
 2020-12-18 00:00:00+00 | squared  |   1 |  3 |     1 |
 2020-12-17 00:00:00+00 | standard |   3 |  1 |     1 |
 2020-12-17 00:00:00+00 | raven    |   2 |  2 |     1 |
 2020-12-17 00:00:00+00 | fox      |   1 |  3 |     1 |
```

I've tried adding a WHERE clause to filter by predictions:

```
where (created_day > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '10 days')
    and word IS NOT NULL
    and prediction = 1
order by created_day DESC, rn;
```

But I get the error `column "prediction" does not exist`.

How would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't want aggregation. You can do the daily count as a window function, then rank using that count:

```
select d.*,
    rank() over(partition by created_day order by cnt) as rn
from (
    select d.created_at, d.label, w.word, 
        count(*) over(partition by date_trunc('day', d.created_at), w.word) as cnt
    from dummy d
    cross join lateral regexp_split_to_table(
        trim(regexp_replace(tweet, '\y(rt|co|https|amp|none)\y', '', 'g')),
        '\s+'
    ) w(word)
    where created_day > current_date - interval '10 days'
) d
```

Comment: Thank you. This returns dates with different times. I was also looking to aggregate by day as well.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you need an aggregation to do what you want, because you have the same label on the same day.  So:

```
select d.*,
       rank() over (partition by created_day order by cnt desc) as rn
from (select d.created_at::date as created_day, d.label, w.word, 
             sum(count(*)) over (partition by d.created_at::date, w.word) as cnt
      from dummy d cross join lateral
           regexp_split_to_table(trim(regexp_replace(tweet, '\y(rt|co|https|amp|none)\y', '', 'g')
                                     ), '\s+'
                                ) w(word)
       where d.created_at >= current_date - interval '10 days'
       group by created_day, d.label, w.word
      ) d
```

Comment: I'm getting an error saying that d.created_day doesn't exist. When I replace with date_trunc('day', s.created_at), I get another error: column "s.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function.

Comment: @mehsheenman . . . Yes.  It is unclear from your question whether `created_at` has a time component or not.  In any case, that should be the date component throughout the query.

Comment: For some reason, the words that are being returned have the same ranking across all labels

Comment: @mehsheenman . . . You need to use a subquery for the filtering:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=58c4a4c433f98ada489c0554e6ddb66a.